# Translation of months / days in the calendar web part

Tags: calendar, multilingual

The OOTB calendar web part does not seem to support translation particularly well - months and days of the week are not translated, but action links and tooltips are.

Can anyone offer a solution to ensure that months and days of the week can be translated too?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the MUI support?

Comment: Yes - that's how I've changed the language from English to Greek, and why I have Greek links within the calendar / on the ribbon etc..

Comment: I can assume the problem is similar to the one you can experience when using the datetimepicker, but considering that you have an hybrid view English/Greek there must be something else going. Will try to see if reflector gives any hint

Comment: no much luck. I have the felling that the problem *is* the same, but I don't understand why part of the control is picking the right locale. I fear the solution is to extend the control.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, I'm not aware of the datepicker problem - can you link me to a description of it?

Comment: Anyone found an answer to this? I have the same issue with Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

I found one way of showing it in the language I want to show it it in, Japanese.

On your site navigate to Site settings -> Site Administration -> Regional settings

On the Regional settings page switch your Local to Greek and click ok. Now you calendar view should be in Greek. That is the solution and the problem, at least for me. It now will be in Greek "Only". so even if you switch back to English user interface the Calendar view will not follow the change and still show your day names in the selected Regional Settings...